# How to plot the graph of this T-sqare Fire Growth

Tags: scilab

I am writing a function to read the label of fire class and the developing time. However, i can only plot the growth stage. How can I plot the other half which is the decay stage to complete the graph as the below link?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7mej.jpg

Here are the codes:

```
function Q3(c,t)
    if c=="S" then
        c=0.0029 
    elseif c=="M" then
        c=0.0117 
    elseif c=="F" then
    c=0.0469 
    elseif c=="U" then
    c=0.1876   
    end
t=0:10:t;
Q=(c)*(t^2);
plot(t,Q,'--r*')
xtitle("The Peak Heat Release Rate = "+string(c*T^2)+"kW")
endfunction
```

The other half is the decay rate, it have the same ratio with the growth rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose this way of plotting your curve:

```
function Q3(c,T)
    if c=="S" then
        c=0.0029 
    elseif c=="M" then
        c=0.0117 
    elseif c=="F" then
    c=0.0469 
    elseif c=="U" then
    c=0.1876   
    end
    t=linspace(0,2*T,1000);
    Q=c*(abs(t-T)-T).^2;
    plot(t,Q,'-')
    xtitle("The Peak Heat Release Rate = "+string(c*T^2)+"kW")
endfunction
```